# Drop down menu css issues

Tags: css

I am trying to;

1. Make the text for each link in the drop down menu to be one line only, not 1 - 3 lines.  I used

   ```
   .mkdf-drop-down .second .inner>ul, 
   li.narrow .second .inner ul { 
      padding-right: 50px !important;  
   }
   ```

   to increase the right
   padding but the title still stops at the original point. I am new to css and learning as I go so I am  wondering if the css is wrong
2. I would also like to remove the underline on the text

I've been researching this for a couple of days now and all I have managed to do is the padding.

Website is http://www.agileseo.com.au/beacon

Answer (score 0):

**Padding** won't help in your case as it will increase the space around the text, so remove it. You must add more **width** to the container.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I realize this forum may be for more advanced coders, I apologize for my lack of knowledge. I tried a few things but was unable to locate the container that relates to the drop down menu. Would you mind helping me further with this. Do I use the same container to remove the underline from the text?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have corrected the issue now